# JSON file data not loading after install flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I am a new learner of android app development with Flutter framework. I am trying to load a JSON file from asset and show the data by listview. It's working with development mode (flutter run) but when I build the apk and install it on my android phone the JSON file is not loading and no data showing on my app.

```
flutter build apk
flutter install
```

I have tried with this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState  extends State<HomePage> {

  List data;

  Future<String> loadZipCodes() async {
    var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/cse.json');
    data = JSON.decode(jsonString);
    print(data[1]);
    return 'success';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.loadZipCodes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
                child: new Container(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(data[index]["sort_term"],style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      new Text(data[index]["long_term"])
                    ])));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Please help me to figure out what is the problem going on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call setState in your loadZipCodes method after setting data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have fixed my problem according to your instruction.    setState(()=> data = JSON.decode(jsonString));

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

give this permission in **app>main>AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

set internet permission in the above file